# How can I count repeated values in the string in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Example:
I have the following string:
201904,BLANK,201902,BLANK,BLANK,201811,201810,201809
How can I count the number of repeated values "BLANK" that goes one by one?
In the described example the answer is 2, but what is the query?
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with BigQuery and I don't want to look rude, but I guess you can esasily find the answer on google by searching for 'bigquery count' or 'bigquery count specific value'

Comment: Leo, if it was a simple thing I would not spend hours searching the answer :)
You suggest to search for the simple Count, but the problem is to count the REPEATED values.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood your example as being the whole result

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (with quick simplified example)

> Corrected Version

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '201904,BLANK,201902,BLANK,BLANK,201811,201810,201809,BLANK,BLANK,BLANK' value UNION ALL
  SELECT '201904,BLANK,201902,BLANK,BLANK,BLANK,201811' UNION ALL
  SELECT '201904,BLANK,201902,BLANK,201811,201902,BLANK,201811'
)
SELECT value, 
  (
    SELECT MAX(ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(list))) - 1 
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(value || ',', r'(?:BLANK,){1,}')) list
  ) max_repeated_count
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

The idea here is

- extract all instances of consecutive BLANK
- split each such instances to array of elements of BLANK
- and finally get max length of those arrays as a result

Just something came as quick approach

> Refactored Version

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '201904,BLANK,201902,BLANK,BLANK,201811,201810,201809,BLANK,BLANK,BLANK' value UNION ALL
  SELECT '201904,BLANK,201902,BLANK,BLANK,BLANK,201811' UNION ALL
  SELECT '201904,BLANK,201902,BLANK,201811,201902,BLANK,201811'
)
SELECT value, 
  (
    SELECT MAX(LENGTH(element) - 1) 
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(REPLACE(value || ',', 'BLANK', ''), r',+')) element
  ) max_repeated_count
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Both with output

```
Row value                                                                   max_repeated_count   
1   201904,BLANK,201902,BLANK,BLANK,201811,201810,201809,BLANK,BLANK,BLANK  3    
2   201904,BLANK,201902,BLANK,BLANK,BLANK,201811                            3    
3   201904,BLANK,201902,BLANK,201811,201902,BLANK,201811                    1
```

Refactored version is slightly different (but main idea the same)

- it removes all BLANKS (assuming BLANK cannot be part of other element - if it can - code can easily be adjusted)
- then extract all consecutive entries of commas into array
- calculates max length of such sequences of commas

Comment: Hi Mikhail. This almost solves the problem, but with some mistake, for example:

value = '201904,BLANK,201902,BLANK,BLANK,BLANK,201811'
Expected result: 3
Current result: 4

value = '201904,BLANK,201902,BLANK,201811'
Expected result: 1
Current result: 2

Comment: as I mentioned - this was quick idea for you to explore - anyway see update - with corrected version and new one  - slightly modified

Comment: Excellent! This is absolutely correct thing! Thanks a lot, Mikhail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood, but can't you simply split by the value you're looking for and subtract 2 (1 for the first element and 1 for counting elements after splitting):

```sql
declare t DEFAULT '201904,BLANK,201902,BLANK,BLANK,201811,201810,201809';

SELECT 
  t as theString,
  split(t,'BLANK') as theSplittedString,
  array_length(split(t,'BLANK'))-2 as theAmount
```

n>0 - amount of repetition,
0 - no repetition,
-1 - element not found

Comment: use sample data from my answer and compare the result / output